# Smooth Scroll Not Working using JQuery in Shopify Theme Debut

Tags: html, jquery, frontend, shopify, liquid

I can not get smooth scrolling using JQuery working in Shopify theme Debut.

I have added the following code above the `</body>` tag in the `theme.liquid` file

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.smooth-scroll').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate(
      { scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top},
      300
    );
  });
});
    </script>
```

The HTML jumps to the correct div id, however, no smooth scrolling is present.

Website: https://bunc.bike/pages/test

Is anyone able to explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're including jQuery in your theme via the `vendor.js` file. That file is inluded via a `<script>` tag with a `defer="defer"` attribute.

From [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer):

> The `defer` attribute tells the browser that it should go on working with the page, and load the script “in background”, then run the script when it loads.

I suspect that if you either:

1. Included your code snippet in the question in your `vendor.js` file, OR
2. Removed the `defer="defer"` attribute from the `vendor.js` file's `<script>` tag

You'd be scrolling very smoothly indeed.

I've proved my thesis with this little gif. The reason it works AFTER I paste your code into the terminal, is because the browser has parsed and loaded the `vendor` file, and `jQuery` is available in the browser's js environment.

[image: Showing the advised strategies in a gif]

Comment: You are a legend! I went with Option 1. and added the code snippet into the `vendor.js` file as I figured this would be best for load times. All working now! Thank you.